# Visual Studio: How to name the .msi output file of an installer project?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer

Greetings,

I have a setup(installer) project in visual studio. I would like to be able to choose what name the msi file that is created when I build the installer.

I've tried to rename the setup project, rename the content project itself, no success.

Anyone could help? I'm sure it's something trivial.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Right click on the MSI project and select **properties**, there is an option on the option page for **"Output file name"**.  Just change that.

I've only checked this under VS2008.

Comment: Is there any way to automate this process bcuz every time Change via VisualStudio not suitable. ??? any help. I have done rename .msi in post build event but on reinstall Error comes.

Comment: I can confirm it's the same for Visual Studio 2015